# sweat alert delete only first row asp.net core html jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

**when i click to delete button on my table sweat alert work on first data only .
In the rest of the rows delete button dosnt work**
help me please thank you

html
in foreach loop of Model

```
<a id="btnRemove" data-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
```

script

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnRemove").on("click", function () {
            var id = $("#btnRemove").data("id");

            swal({
                title: 'Do you want to Delete it?',
                text: 'info info ....!',
                icon: 'warning',
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true
            }).then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "DELETE",
                        url: "/EmployeeLeaveTypes/Delete/" + id,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                toastr.success(data.message);
                                location.reload();
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(data.message);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: you working with an id, try to work with a class instead multiple buttons with the same id might cause such problems. also use $(this) inside your function to get the id of the record to delete

Comment: Should not be proprietary `id` . this is a unique element in HTML tag . Solve : create a `function` in javascripts  or use `className` in tag `a`

Comment: @Isparia , Thank you Sir  its working  'class="btnRemove" ' in script i changed from '#btnRemove' to ' .btnRemove '

Comment: Thank you too for feedback @MohammadrezaGolshahi its working

Comment: @SabZero well since you fixed it answer your own question, stack overflow encourages it

Comment: @Isparia Ok sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix :
i changed the id in a tag from `id="btnRemove"` to `class="btnRemove"`
and in the script i also changed
 `$("#btnRemove").on("click", function ()` to

```
 $('.btnRemove').on("click", function ()
```

then sweat alert for all rows is working

---

and for delete function foreache row
 `var id = $("#btnRemove").data("id");` to
 `var id = $(this).data("id");`

then the delete function is working and delete every row .

thank you Programmers Community